# Garbage in Eclipse console log

Tags: eclipse, logging, garbage

I have a problem with logs display in my eclipse console. The japanese characters displayed in starting and stopping the weblogic server are garbage. There is no problem however with the logs written by the application. I am using log4j. 
Log4j.properties

```
# Log4JLogger\u521d\u671f\u5316\u30d1\u30e9\u30e1\u30bf\u8a2d\u5b9a

# \u30ed\u30b0\u30ec\u30d9\u30eb\u3001\u30a2\u30da\u30f3\u30c0\u540d\u8a2d\u5b9a
log4j.rootCategory=INFO, consoleLog, consolefileLog

# \u30ed\u30b0\u30ec\u30d9\u30eb\u306e\u8a73\u7d30\u8a2d\u5b9a
log4j.category.jp.terasoluna=DEBUG
log4j.category.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.category.org.apache.struts=INFO
log4j.category.com.ibatis=DEBUG
log4j.category.java.sql=DEBUG

# This is the category for operations Logger class
# Do not change unless you know exactly what you are doing
#log4j.category.jp.co.anicom.fw.common.log.Logger=DEBUG, fileLog
log4j.category.opLog=DEBUG, fileLog

# \u30b3\u30f3\u30bd\u30fc\u30eb\u30a2\u30da\u30f3\u30c0\u8a2d\u5b9a
log4j.appender.consoleLog=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.consoleLog.Target = System.out
log4j.appender.consoleLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consoleLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d{yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss}][%p][%C{1}] %m%n
#log4j.appender.consoleLog.encoding=UTF-8

log4j.appender.consolefileLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.consolefileLog.File = anicomConsole.log
log4j.appender.consolefileLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.consolefileLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %m%n
log4j.appender.consolefileLog.encoding=UTF-8


# \u30d5\u30a1\u30a4\u30eb\u30a2\u30da\u30f3\u30c0\u8a2d\u5b9a
log4j.appender.fileLog=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.fileLog.File = anicomOp.log
log4j.appender.fileLog.layout = org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.fileLog.layout.ConversionPattern=[%d] %m%n
log4j.appender.fileLog.encoding=UTF-8
# Global logging configuration

log4j.logger.com.ibatis=DEBUG

# shows SQL of prepared statements
log4j.logger.java.sql=DEBUG
log4j.logger.java.sql.Connection=DEBUG

# shows parameters inserted into prepared statements
log4j.logger.java.sql.PreparedStatement=DEBUG

# shows query results
log4j.logger.java.sql.ResultSet=DEBUG

log4j.logger.java.sql.Statement=DEBUG
```

=================================================================================

## I also have these in my eclipse console. As you can see it displays garbage

CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1031\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\utils\config\10.3.1.0\config-launch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_10.3.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.0/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\common\eval\pointbase\lib\pbclient57.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\xqrl.jar
.
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1031\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.0\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\jre\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin;C:\app\em.alcuizar\product\11.1.0\client_2\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\app\em.alcuizar\product\11.1.0\db_1\bin;C:\product\11.1.0\client_1;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin;D:\Data\Installers\Java\oepe-ganymede-all-in-one-11.1.1.3.0.200910091510-win32\eclipse\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.7.0.v200803061910\bin;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\native\win\32\oci920_8
.

---

- To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *
- password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *
- server administration, use the WebLogic Server *
- console at http:\hostname:port\console        *

  ---

starting weblogic with Java version:
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
java version "1.6.0_11"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_11-b03)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 11.0-b16, mixed mode)
Starting WLS with line:
C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\JDK160~1\bin\java -client -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8453,server=y,suspend=n -Djava.compiler=NONE  -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=48m  -XX:MaxPermSize=128m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server\lib\weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none  -ea -da:com.bea... -da:javelin... -da:weblogic... -ea:com.bea.wli... -ea:com.bea.broker... -ea:com.bea.sbconsole... -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.3\server   -Dweblogic.management.discover=true  -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1031\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath  weblogic.Server
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 8453
<2010/11/03 15��12��30�b SGT>    <���̊g���q�f�B���N�g���̓��e���N���X�p�X�̌��ɒǉ�����܂��� :
C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\beehive_ja.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\beehive_ko.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\beehive_zh_CN.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\beehive_zh_TW.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\p13n_wls_ja.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\p13n_wls_ko.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\p13n_wls_zh_CN.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\p13n_wls_zh_TW.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\testclient_ja.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\testclient_ko.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\testclient_zh_CN.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\testclient_zh_TW.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\tuxedocontrol_ja.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\tuxedocontrol_ko.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\tuxedocontrol_zh_CN.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\tuxedocontrol_zh_TW.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\workshop_ja.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\workshop_ko.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\workshop_zh_CN.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_10.3\L10N\workshop_zh_TW.jar> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��30�b SGT>     
<2010/11/03 15��12��31�b SGT>    <�o�[�W����: WebLogic Server 10.3.1.0  Wed Jun 10 22:24:41 MDT 2009 1227385 > 
<2010/11/03 15��12��33�b SGT>    <�T�[�o��Ԃ� STARTING �ɕω����܂����B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��33�b SGT>    <�����`���[�j���O �X���b�h �v�[���������Ă��܂��B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��33�b SGT>    <���O �t�@�C�� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log �̓��[�e�[�V��������܂��B��������~�����ꍇ�́A���O �t�@�C�����ăI�[�v�����Ă��������B����́AWindows �Ȃǈꕔ�̃v���b�g�t�H�[���ŋN����\��������܂��B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��33�b SGT>    <���O �t�@�C���� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log01940 �܂Ń��[�e�[�V��������܂����B���O ���b�Z�[�W�͈��� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log �ɋL�^����܂��B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��33�b SGT>    <�T�[�o ���O �t�@�C�� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\AdminServer.log ���J���܂����B���ׂẴT�[�o�T�C�h ���O �C�x���g�͂��̃t�@�C���ɏ������܂�܂��B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��38�b SGT>    <�Z�L�����e�B�̓Z�L�����e�B ������ myrealm ���g�p���ď����Ă��܂��B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��40�b SGT>    <���O �t�@�C�� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\access.log �̓��[�e�[�V��������܂��B��������~�����ꍇ�́A���O �t�@�C�����ăI�[�v�����Ă��������B����́AWindows �Ȃǈꕔ�̃v���b�g�t�H�[���ŋN����\��������܂��B> 
<2010/11/03 15��12��40�b SGT>    <���O �t�@�C���� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\access.log01446 �܂Ń��[�e�[�V��������܂����B���O ���b�Z�[�W�͈��� C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\teraproto\servers\AdminServer\logs\access.log �ɋL�^����܂��B>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the Console view of Eclipse utilizes an appropriate font with the necessary glyphs, it is possible that the Japanese characters appear mangled, for that is the behavior of most applications - any glyph for a Unicode character that is absent in the font, will appear as a question mark.

One of the possible solutions is to change the font utilized in the debug console, to one that supports display of most Unicode characters, especially characters in the ISO-8859-1 and the Hiragana or Katagana character sets. In Eclipse, this can be configured from Window -> Preferences -> General -> Apperance -> Colors and Fonts, and by changing the font of the Debug Console (or the Terminal console, I'm not sure which).

Comment: Weird, i've changed it to unifont but ` System.out.print("\u0061\u0300");` is still giving me a question mark behind: `a?`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Workspace and change at the bottom "Text file encoding" section to Other: "UTF-8" and "New text file line delimiter" to Other: "Unix"